# Does C/C++ program performance depend on compiler?

Tags: c++, c, performance, compiler-construction

I read an article in which different compilers were compared to infer which is the best in different circumstances. It gave me a thought. Even though I tried to google, I didn't manage to find a clear and lucid answer: will the program run faster or slower if I use different compilers to compile it? Suppose, it's some uncommon complicated algorithm that is used along with templating.

Comment: Yes that's possible

Comment: Yes it may also depend on compiler settings like optimization level. I have seen cases were a debug build of an application took 100 times as long to run as a release version of the same application and the same data.

Comment: Not only can there be differences between comilers, but even the same compiler with different compiler options can yield drastically different performances. In the end you probably have to benchmark your code to choose the best compiler. Be sure that doing this is actually worth your time. With this kind of research you could end up spending a lot of time for a neglectible improvement in performance...

Comment: *will the program run faster or slower if I use different compilers to compile it?* -- If you were alive and sentient back in the 1990's, compiler vendors would routinely have ads in computer magazines where "our compiler is faster than the other brand's compiler".   Borland would compete against Watcom, Watcom would compete against Borland and Zortech, etc.  So the answer is basically "Yes" to your question.  This is back in the day when compilers were expensive (not free like today), and a company really had to make a big decision on which compiler to buy and use for their applications.

Comment: It is true for every language. Implementation of /compiler/interpreter/virtual machine/any other intermediate between your program text and hardware/ matter

Comment: As an anecdotal example, I'm writing some multi-precision BCD code.  Obviously dividing by 10 is needed to convert binary to BCD.   Using Compiler Explorer I found that gcc and clang emit different code for it.  clang emits an actual `DIV` instruction.  gcc uses a multiplicative inverse followed by a right shift, which is much faster.  Likely clang emits more efficient code than gcc for some other things, but it shows that which compiler will emit faster code depends on how what your code does lines up with the particular optimizations that the compiler implements.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.  The compiler is what writes a program that implements the behavior you've described with your C or C++ code.  Different compilers (or even the same compiler, given different options) can come up with vastly different programs that implement the same behavior.

Remember, your CPU does not execute C or C++ code.  It only executes machine code.  There is no defined standard for how the former gets transformed into the latter.

Answer (score 2):

It may depend on the compiler, compiler version, compiler optimization settings, C++ language version used when compiling, the linker used, linker optimization options and much more. So in short, the answer to your question is *Yes*.